# Typescript reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

When I'm trying to get the states through mapStateToProps function, it's giving me property does not exist on type `never`

This is the snippet code of setup for the reducers, I'm also using redux saga and redux persist here

```
// combine all reducers
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  dashboard: dashboardReducer,
  sales: salesReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;

// set config to our rootreducer
const pReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer); //ERROR ON rootReducer HERE

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
// use the new persistreducer in creating store
const store = createStore(pReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)));

const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

**Note:** `rootReducer` returns error when I'm setting persist config using persistReducer.

Below is the error when I hovered over `rootReducer` in the `persistReducer` function

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<CombinedState<{
    dashboard: never;
    sales: never;
    auth: never;
}>, AppActions>
Argument of type 'Reducer<CombinedState<{ dashboard: never; sales: never; auth: never; }>, AppActions>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<unknown, AppActions>'.
  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ dashboard: never; sales: never; auth: never; }> | undefined'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'CombinedState<{ dashboard: never; sales: never; auth: never; }>'.
        Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined; }'.ts(2345)
```

Then I tried to get rid of the error by doing this, which obviously doesn't work out well and it led to the `type never` errors afterwards, but other than doing this, I'm not sure how else to suppress the error.

> const pReducer = persistReducer<`RootState`>(persistConfig, rootReducer);

Then in one of my TSX file when I tried to get the states

```
interface StateProps {
  loading: boolean;
  authenticated: boolean;
  errorMessage: string | null;
  userInfoObj: TReceivedUserInfoObj | null;
}
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps | void => {
  return {
    loading: state.auth.loading,
    errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage,
    userInfoObj: state.auth.userInfoObj,
    authenticated: state.auth.auth_token !== null,
  };
};
```

And it's giving me type never errors

```
Property 'loading' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339

    108 | const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState): StateProps | void => {
    109 |   return {
  > 110 |     loading: state.auth.loading,
        |                         ^
    111 |     errorMessage: state.auth.errorMessage,
    112 |     userInfoObj: state.auth.userInfoObj,
    113 |     authenticated: state.auth.auth_token !== null,
```

Also, when I hovered over the `<typeof rootReducer>`, this is what I'm seeing

```
const rootReducer: Reducer<CombinedState<{
    dashboard: never;
    sales: never;
    auth: never;
}>, AppActions>
```

`authReducer` when I hover over it

```
(alias) const authReducer: (state: AuthInitialState | undefined, action: AuthActionTypes) => {} | undefined
import authReducer
```

*`AuthInitialState`* the types for initial states in auth reducer

```
// initialState for reducers
export interface AuthInitialState {
  readonly loading: boolean;
  readonly errorMessage: string | null;
  readonly successMessage: string | null;
  // user info
  readonly userInfoObj: TReceivedUserInfoObj | null;
  // auth token
  readonly auth_token: string | null;
}
```

*`AuthActionTypes`* A bunch of interfaces of actions union into one type

```
export type AuthActionTypes = 
  | SignInAction
  | SignInStartAction
  | SignInSucceedAction
  | SignInFailedAction
 
  | SignOutAction
 
  | GetUserInfoAction
  | GetUserInfoStartAction
  | GetUserInfoSucceedAction
  | GetUserInfoFailedAction;
```

example of sign in actions

```
export interface SignInAction {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SIGN_IN;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface SignInStartAction {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SIGN_IN_START;
}

export interface SignInSucceedAction {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SIGN_IN_SUCCEED;
  auth_token: string;
}

export interface SignInFailedAction {
  type: typeof actionTypes.SIGN_IN_FAILED;
  errorMessage: string;
}
```

In short, my problem here is unable to setup `rootReducer` smoothly with redux persist and causing states to be type `never` when extracting states through mapStateToProps

My apology if the post got a little too long and hard to read, thanks for all your patience and help in advance.

---

**UPDATE**
I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363371/redux-reducer-type-never) and implemented the Reducer<State, ActionType> thing. Now the type `never` error is gone, but new issue arises.

In my auth.ts reducer file,

```
const reducer: Reducer<AuthInitialState, AuthActionTypes> = (state = initialState, action) => {
```

It's now giving me this error

```
const reducer: Reducer<AuthInitialState, AuthActionTypes>
Type '(state: AuthInitialState | undefined, action: AuthActionTypes) => {} | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<AuthInitialState, AuthActionTypes>'.
  Type '{} | undefined' is not assignable to type 'AuthInitialState'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'AuthInitialState'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#type-checking-reducers

Comment: Typescript should be smart enough to infer the correct typo. You could simpre remove `: any` and let typescript assign/infer the correct type automatically,

Comment: Could you please show us instead what you did and what error you have? As @Rumpelstinsk rightly pointed out, let typescript infer the correct type instead.

Comment: Added more details on what i did, I dont really know what I'm doing tbh with the redux types here, I just followed some tutorials on youtube and mimic the way they declare types for their mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Answer (score 0):

Note that we do not have to explicitly declare a new interface for RootState. We can use `ReturnType` to infer state shape from the `rootReducer`.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  dashboard: dashboardReducer,
  sales: salesReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
```

[checkout this official redux docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript)